# Maven activating profiles

Tags: maven

I have 4 profiles in maven (A,B,C,D). I want to activate A by default when B and C are not activated. Can I have some configuration which will enable that ? 
If I use activeByDefault for A then A is not activated when D is activated.
Hence to summarize it should work as follows:

mvn package -P B     (A should not be activated)

mvn package -P C     (A should not be activated)

mvn package -P D     (A should be activated)

mvn package          (A should be activated)

Comment: I can only guess that it's because your question is for a non straightforward puzzle and you give little informations about the context. The first question someone would ask you is: "Why in hell do you want to do that". Sometimes, the real answer is to simplify your real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me mention what worked for me.
I will define these profiles as follows:

```
<profile>
  <id>A</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>!Type</name>
    </property>
   </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>B</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>Type</name>
      <value>B</value>
    </property>
   </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>C</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>Type</name>
      <value>C</value>
    </property>
   </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>D</id>
</profile>
```

Now following will work (though its a bit hacky!) as I asked: 
**mvn package -DType=B (A should not be activated) 

mvn package -PType=C (A should not be activated) 

mvn package -P D (A should be activated) 

mvn package (A should be activated)**

Answer (score 0):

Maven profiles can be activated via configuration:

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html#profiles-sect-activation-config

But unfortunately, activation/deactivation upon a certain set of activated profiles in not part of what you can do.

I would be curious to know more about the context and the underlying reason for which you want to do that. If you can give us more informations.

The reason I ask is because it looks rather over complicated. Couldn't you use a few bash scripts in order to launch the right profiles? More importantly, is it really problematic to have profile A activated?